# Automating download of executable which is within several nested urls by listening to build triggers

Tags: python, download, urllib2

Is there a way by which I can click on the most latest url on a web page, then url within it, to download an exe file in python.

I know how to do download files from a static url but what about changing urls?

Note: I want to go to most latest url out of all urls. then I need to again click a url within it. Later, download the file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your need is a very specific task. You can download the page (requests package is more recommended over the built-in urllib2), then use BeautifulSoup package (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to extract correct URLs from the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used BeautifulSoup to accomplish this as suggested by ZZY. Thanks ZZY. Basically, we can do something like this:

```
    page = self.authorizedopen(username, password, url)
    text = page.read()
    page.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    data = ''
    for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
        data = tag['href']

    return url + '/' + data
```

And constantly manipulated the url to reach where I want to. Then used simple urlib2 to download the required file.